# How do i create an animated (moving from left to right) waveform in Python?

Tags: python, pyaudio

I need to create moving waveform using Python and pyaudio. I thought about creating a buffer and filling it with data from audio stream. It sorta works but it's too slow. I tried changing the size of chunk to something smaller, but i always get an "Input overflowed" error.

This is the code i came up with

```
import numpy as np
import pyaudio as pa
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

CHUNK = 1024
FORMAT = pa.paInt16
CHANNELS = 1
RATE = 44100

p = pa.PyAudio()

stream = p.open(
    format = FORMAT,
    channels = CHANNELS,
    rate = RATE,
    input=True,
    output=True,
    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK
)

buffer = [0]*CHUNK

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
x = np.arange(0,2*CHUNK,2)
line, = ax.plot(x, np.random.rand(CHUNK),'r')
ax.set_ylim(-32000,32000)
ax.ser_xlim = (0,CHUNK)
fig.show()
while True:
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    dataInt = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.int16)
    for i in range(len(dataInt)):
        buffer.insert(0, dataInt[i])
        del buffer[-1]
        line.set_ydata(buffer)
        fig.canvas.draw()
        fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

Comment: Hi, first let me ask to see if I understood the problem correctly. If the first buffer is like:
`A1A2A3...A1024` and then the next buffer is `B1B2...B1024` what you draw in the for loop is like:
`A1A2...A1024,
B1A1...A1023,
B2B1...A1022,
...` 
so it reverses the second buffer and plots it one by one. Is this what you wanted?

Comment: @ses I want to update buffer so the waveform line moves from left to right, for that i store data in buffer, in which i push new values and delete old values. Sothe buffer goes like: A1A2A3...A1024, then with next push it should look like A2A3A4...A1023A1024B1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that the update in the for loop is too frequent and we know each update in the data and redrawing the canvas is time-consuming. I suggest making the update once every few datapoints. You can control update frequency using a variable like `UPDATE_SIZE`:

```py
UPDATE_SIZE = 32
while True:
    data = stream.read(CHUNK)
    dataInt = np.frombuffer(data, dtype=np.int16)
    for i in range(0, len(dataInt), UPDATE_SIZE):
        buffer = dataInt[i:i+UPDATE_SIZE].tolist()[::-1] + buffer[:-UPDATE_SIZE]
        line.set_ydata(buffer)
        fig.canvas.draw()
        fig.canvas.flush_events()
```

Comment: Thank you, i've played a little bit wit chunk size and update size and it works much better now